# SQL query to compare rows

Tags: sql, compare

I have a table like this:

```
    Sequence    ID      Date          other fields

    1           23      2012-01-01
    2           23      2012-02-03
    3           23      2012-02-02
    4           45      2012-01-01
    5           45      2012-01-02
    6           52      2012-01-01
    7           52      2012-03-01
    ..          ...
```

I need a query that returns me rows that have inversed dates(there is a higher sequence with an older date

in example abow it should return rowq with sequence 2 and 3. For id 23, Seq 2 has date newer that sequence no 3.

Thanks

Comment: I have updated my answer.. Please check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from 
   (select T1.Sequence as S1, T2.Sequence as S2, T1.ID 
    from T as T1, T as T2
    where T1.Sequence < T2.Sequence 
      and T1.Date > T2.Date 
      and T1.ID = T2.ID) Subq
   inner join T on (T.ID = Subq.ID 
               and (T.Sequence = Subq.S1 or T.Sequence = Subq.S2))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select t1.*
from <table> t1
  join <table> t2 
    on  t1.Id=t2.Id
    and (((t1.Sequence>t2.Sequence) and (t1.Date<t2.Date)) or
         ((t1.Sequence<t2.Sequence) and (t1.Date>t2.Date)))
```

And the fiddle for it http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/beaf8/2/0

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
select Sequence,ID,Date 
from   
   ( select *,
     ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by ID order by date) as row_num_date,
     ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by ID order by Sequence) as row_num_seq
     from your_table )a
where row_num_date!=row_num_seq
```

## [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/aac41/2)